# Horizontal block alignment in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning to bear with me.

I want to have 3 separate blocks within a container, and through css have them inlined, for example

the html (rough idea)

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="block1">
        <img scr="blockimage1" />
    </div>

    <div class="block2">
        <img scr="blockimage2" />
    </div>

    <div class="block3">
        <img scr="blockimage3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

the css (rough idea)

```
.content-containter
{
  width:1500px;
  margin:40px auto 0 auto;
  padding:10px;
}

.block1
{
  width:500px;
  float:left;
}

.block2
{
  width:500px;
  float:center;
}

.block3
{
  width:500px;
  float:right;
}
```

What's happening to me is they are just all aligning vertically below each other. Not next to each other in a horizontal line. I've tried many things and the closest I got was making a grid system with bootstrap but I ran issues with that later on so I thought I'd try a new approach.

Comment: There is no `float:center`. And both your HTML and CSS syntax are completely wrong.

Comment: Is my markup better? 
Sorry, I wrote it quick without thinking. 
I apologize!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clean your HTML, CSS and use a simple solution. View the result in full screen. Display the blocks in a line using `display: inline-block`

```css
.content-containter
{
  width:1500px;
  margin:40px auto 0 auto;
  padding:10px;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    </div>


    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
   </div>

    <div class="block">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect!, at the same time though. Each block will have diffrent content, but will be the same size. 
Using your solution through the css with ".block", I'd have to style each block indivually then? or can I just do it as a whole by doing the same display:inline with the "content-container" class?

Comment: You can have different content since HTML defines the content and not CSS, but if you want to style individually, you can use ID(#) or CSS pseudo-selectors like `:nth-child` `:nth-of-type`.

Comment: In using this solution, one thing I've noticed is it will not scale and be neatly aligned when browser size changes. Any recommendation for that?

Comment: Well, I answered with respect to your question. There will be shortcomings when you implement it altering the content. You will need to use media-queries for browser resizing boundary check. Better to use a Frontend framework like Bootstrap.